# Are words like "scissors" plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

I never hear "scissor" or "pant" or "jean". It's always "scissors", "pants", and "jeans", respectively. Are they considered plural?

Comment: It is probably a relic from the days when pants and leggings did not cover the butt and pelvis, and so came in pairs, one for each leg. We do have "a scissor kick".

Comment: (Pair of) Underwear, underpants, and panties always gets my boxers in a bunch.

Comment: Scissor lift, pant leg, jean shorts.

Comment: Well, pant is definitely a word. What's the word to describe half of a scissors? Like if one half broke off

Comment: @Huangism Usually it's called a blade.

Comment: I have seen a half of scissors being called "a scissor".

Comment: Poor choice of dupe. Linked question asks for definition of "scissor" and "trouser" and the answer gives it for those two specific words. *This* question asks if words like this are plural, which is not asked by the dupe question or addressed by the dupe answers at all...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, these words only have a plural form and require the verb in the plural.  A list of such words would be very long and, to mention just a few:

> - glasses (spectacles)
> - trousers
> - binoculars
> - tweezers
> - pajamas, pyjamas
> - knickers
> - clothes
> - belongings
>
> but beware of "maths" and  "aerobics" which are always singular.

For a complete list, follow the links:

> - [nouns which are always plural in form](http://mentalfloss.com/article/52672/11-nouns-only-have-plural-form)
> - [nouns that only have a plural form](http://mentalfloss.com/article/52672/11-nouns-only-have-plural-form)

Comment: Your warning about maths and aerobics is incorrect. [Maths is a perfectly valid word](http://grammarist.com/spelling/math-maths/). It is a regional distinction, like flavor/flavour. And aerobics is just a shortening of "aerobic exercises."

Comment: The OP was about "words" not just "nouns", the singulars are often used as adjectives, e.g. "scissor lift", "pant leg", "binocular lens", "I have a tweezer drawer that I keep my tweezers in", etc. Some still don't use the singular in adjective form, though, e.g. you'll never find a "clothe" anything.

Comment: The singular is often used in verb form as well, e.g. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scissor, "to scissor something". I am not sure that the assertion that the plural verb is required is correct, either, e.g. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scissor although I cannot think of an example.

Comment: @Darrick Herwehe I think Centaurus's warning about maths and aerobics is not about the math/maths regional variation, but refers to the fact that these words are always treated as singular in spite of looking like plurals. I (a Brit, if you can't tell) would say "Maths is my favourite subject", but never "Maths are my favourite subject".

Comment: @JasonC "Clothe" is a perfectly normal and common verb - https://duckduckgo.com/?q=clothe

Comment: @AnonymousMonkey I was describing adjectives in that comment. I thought "you'll never find a 'clothe' anything" pretty clearly did not refer to a verb. Verbs are in the following comment.

Comment: @Nefrubyr That's possible, but I read it as "absolutely, never, never are these ok." I just wanted to make sure anyone else who came across this didn't take it that way.

Comment: -1 you can find judicious instances of *scissor* in Google Books.

Answer (score 5):

> They are termed as [duals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_(grammatical_number)) : denoting a form of a word indicating
>   that exactly two referents are being referred to.

Consider these :
trousers, panties, glasses, binoculars, both, couple, legs, arms, feet, [youse](https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en-IN&source=hp&q=yous%20meaning&gbv=2&oq=yous%20me&gs_l=heirloom-hp.3.0.0j0i10l9.1577.3765.0.4858.7.7.0.0.0.0.281.890.0j4j1.5.0.msedrc...0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-hp..2.5.874.RjjoE2KiMhk), pair etc.

The singular form is commonly used in compound words such as: scissor-hands, spectacle-case etc.

```
Scissor used in the singular as a verb may not be grammatically wrong.
```

Comment: Is "scissor-hands" really commonly used? Before Edward Scissorhands I mean?

Comment: @Araucaria, good you brought it up. I referred to the dual markers. Legs, arms, feet and twins are things that occur in pairs and couples.

Comment: @MystiSinha but legs don't only occur in twos! neither do feet! :)

Comment: @Araucaria On normal humans they do.

Answer (score 3):

Words like "jeans", "scissors", "pants" are non-count nouns. Anything that you cannot buy as a single item (I'd like to buy 1 pant, please) or items that can only be counted in terms of "X's of Y" (pairs of pants/bottles of milk/grains of sand) are non-count.

They don't truly exist as singular or plural. However, we generally use plural verbs with them. "My pants are torn" not "My pants is torn."

Comment: I fully agree, but can you add a decent authority that backs this up? (CGEL requires a count-noun [usage] to accept a numeral, for instance.)

Comment: And note that 'separates' is also always plural-form, never count. **_But_** whereas 'I've spilt ketchup on my jeans / pants / tights' almost always refers to a single referent (garment), 'Separates are upstairs, madam' never does.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're plural as Centaurus says. You would say "pass me those binoculars", never "pass me that binoculars"* or "pass me that binocular"*. But as Xen2050 points out, many of those can be used with the classifier "pair" ("A pair of binoculars", "a pair of knickers") in which case the head of the noun phrase is the singular "pair", making the entire noun phrase singular.

Beware of a couple of alternative meanings, though. Centaurus has already flagged "glasses" as only always being plural when it refers to the things you wear in front of your eyes - the type of glass one drinks from behaves "normally" as a known. I avoided using "spectacles" in the clarification, though, because that too has another meaning (noteworthy sights) that can be singular. Similarly, "knicker" is (somewhat archaic) British slang for a pound, and as far as I can tell stays the same in singular and plural.

Comment: The "pound" word is spelled *nicker*.

Comment: So it is. But the stone used in some children's games is spelled "knicker", so there is still a word with that spelling.

Answer (score 0):

English has a lot of particularities as to numerus (singular and plural). One group of plural nouns are things that consist of two parts. In English grammars these nouns are often called "pair nouns".
Such nouns are

trousers, shorts, pyjamas, braces

scissors, tongs, spectacles, glasses, compasses

lungs

Verbs after these nouns have plural form and when referring to one object you use 
"a pair of" as in a pair of trousers.

I would not mix these pair nouns with other nouns used in plural form as clothes, belongings etc.

The Oxford Guide to English Grammar has pair nouns in paragraph 155. In other languages these pair nouns in plural form may correspond to a noun in singular as 
in German Schere (singular) for scissors.

Answer (score -1):

I think they are plural, sort of, so far as they each have two (nearly identical) pieces (each leg, scissor blade/side) so they're like a set. A pair of pants/jeans, or scissors.

Maybe someone knows the history of the words? Were pants worn one leg at a time, separately, somewhere in the past?

Comment: Actually, yes, in different time periods. Plate armor came in separate pieces for different sides of the body. And at one time, jacket sleeves basically had to be sewn on every day. We wear "pairs of glasses" because we first had "monocles".

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the above mentioned words are plural. If you mean 'a pair of scissors' than rules for singular nouns apply.